# Unable to load images which are inside partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a main view with a image tag which works fine

**Main View :**

```
<div>
<img src="images/sample.png" alt="dash">
<a href="~/Main/Test">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

**Partial View :**

```
<div>
<img src="images/sample.png" alt="dash">
</div>
```

When i click on `Click Me` it will load a different view which having my image tag which is not loading properly .

I have checked the console and i can see error `404 (Not Found)` and url is prefixed by `Main` . image src looks like this `Main/images/sample1.png` in console .

Any idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [Url.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx)

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/images/sample.png")" />
```

Comment: its not working still i see `Main` getting appended . any ideas ?

Comment: ok is this what you looking for mainApplication(project) -> scripts,images,controllers(home-index & submain action methods),views(-Home folder(-index view(index action) & - submain view(submain action methid) ) .